# Dummy ASIO service callback?

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I have an ASIO-based object that does network communications, and there's a small fix I need to make, but it involves adding a dummy request and callback to an ASIO io_service.

I have an interface function that I need to support for client code, but with a recent change in my implementation this interface function no longer does anything.

```
void MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported( 
    boost::function< void( int ) > callback );
```

The client code for the interface is expecting a callback some time after it makes the call. Previously, the implementation might have looked something like:

```
void MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported( 
    boost::function< void( int ) > callback )
{
    boost::asio::async_write(m_socket_previously_connected, 
                         m_request_buf_previously_filled, 
                         boost::bind( &MyClass::HandleAsyncWriteCompletion,
                                     this,
                                     boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                     callback ) );
}

void MyClass::HandleAsyncWriteCompletion( 
    const boost::system::error_code& e, 
    boost::function< void( int ) > originalCallback )
{
    if(!e) // Write operation completed successfully
    {
        orignalCallback( 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        orignalCallback( -1 );
    }    
}
```

Now, `MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported` does nothing at all, but the client still expects it to be there and will continue to call it. I could do this:

```
void MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported( 
    boost::function< void( int ) > callback )
{
    callback( 0 );
}
```

...but this is a bit dangerous, because the client will be getting the callback at an unexpected time - during its call to `MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported`. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
void MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported( 
    boost::function< void( int ) > callback )
{
    // Set the timeout and asynchronously wait
    m_zero_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(0));
    m_zero_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&MyClass::ZeroTimerExpiry,
                                            this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            callback ) );
}


void MyClass::ZeroTimerExpiry( const boost::system::error_code & e, 
    boost::function< void( int ) > orignalCallback )
{
    orignalCallback( 0 );
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of getting the callback to come on io_service::run() other than using a zero-timer?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`io_service::post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html)?

Comment: `post()` will ensure that your client keeps getting the callback in the same manner (and within the same thread(s)) as prior to this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way of getting the callback to come on io_service::run() other than using a zero-timer?

Sure, here it is:

```
void MyClass::FuncThatNoLongerDoesAnythingButMustBeSupported( 
    boost::function< void( int ) > callback )
{
    io.post( boost::bind(callback, 0) );
}
```

If you dont have the `io_service` reference, you can obtain it from `m_zero_timer.get_io_service()`